# Flask filter by url

Tags: python, flask, flask-restless

I'm using Flask-Restless and Flask-SQLAlchemy on my application. I can't remember when, but I did a example that I'm almost 100% it was with Flask-Restless to filter a query in the url like /example?id=1. Although the pagination plugin is ok, I can't replicate the filtering by attribute on the url.

I've been searching like crazy on how to do that again but I can't find it. I'd appreciate if someone here has a way of doing that.

PS.: With Flask-Restless, how do I make a GET request on a endpoint passing a parameter like GET /example {"id": 1}?

PS2.: I know that if I put the id after the "/" I'll get the object, but I want to filter any field I want.

Comment: https://flask-restless.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filtering.html

Comment: @Craicerjack I've tried that method but it didn't worked. I got an error saying it couldn't parse the query or something like that. Do you have an example of that query method?

Comment: Ok, I could make the filtering by url but in a rather ugly way. I'm still accepting other suggestions.

Comment: Could you edit your question to explain what you want? You first stated you want to query by id and then by more. Can you give an example?

Comment: @Craicerjack I want to query by any field I want, sorry for not make myself clear.

Comment: This - https://flask-restless.readthedocs.io/en/stable/searchformat.html - what you are looking for?